# Fancy Sliding Form with jQuery Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a junior programmer and struggling with a plugin.

Everything works well except when you want to confirm all the details. The confirmation page display incorrectly and you can't see the whole page.

Any ideas to what I am doing wrong?

Here is a link to the single page with the form:
http://www.creatiffweb.co.za/emillingTester/list.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your calculation of the `widths` array. Some child elements of your pages (the `fieldset.step` elements) also have the class `step`. That's because you are calculating too much widths and for the last page the width is too short.

This results in the page being only half displayed. Then you focus the button on the page, which is not entirely visible yet. The browser then scrolls your steps to the left to fully show the button and breaks the layout.

You should propably adjust the selector to something like the following, to only include the actual pages:

```
$('#steps fieldset.step').each(function(i) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried what you have suggested - the navigation bar now stays put, but the page does the same as usual. I feel lost. I have updated the files: http://creatiffweb.co.za/emillingTester/list.html

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough. What I meant is in line 18 in the file sliding.form.js. The part, where you calculate the widths of the different steps. Just have a look at the widths array after it was populated and you will see that there are too many entries.